# How to check every checkboxes in a jquery datatable fixed cloumn on click of a button

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable

I am using jquery datatable fixed column plug-in to fix the first column in the table. 
This column has checkboxes. 
This table has more than 1 page. 
How to check every checkboxes in this table as the checkbox column is a fixed column.

Here the datatable's fnGetNodes() method does not bring the fixed column nodes:

```
$('input.daisyChk').each(function (e) { 
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
    this.removeAttribute("checked");

    //Get the row index 
    var rowIndex = $(this).val(); 

    Selecteditems.splice(Selecteditems.indexOf(rowIndex), 1);

   /*Update the datatable row column */ 
   var res = $('#daisyexample').dataTable()
       .fnUpdate($($(this).parent()).html(),
           parseInt(rowIndex, 10), 0, false, true); 

   $('#daisyexample').dataTable()
       .fnStandingRedraw($('#daisyexample').dataTable().f‌​nSettings()); 
});
```

I tried getting all the nodes using,

$('#daisyexample').dataTable().fnGetNodes();

but i am ble to get just the columns that are not fixed. As the check box column is fixed i am not able to get that.

Comment: You need to show some code that you have tried. And **do not** link as you seem to have attempted to, but failed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please edit your question **do not** post in comments